# View recently recorded videos from camera on Apple Watch?

Tags: software-recommendation, video, apple-watch, camera, video-capture

It looks like I can only view recently taken photos. Is there an Apple Watch where this works? Mine is old, a series 3 running watchOS  8.7 and I consider buying new hardware a fix if newer watches allow this.

Is it possible to watch a recently recorded, 30 second video taken from iPhone remotely by apple watch from the camera remote app?

If someone could check, open the Camera app on iphone, click "video". Then open the Camera Remote app on your watch, and start recording the video. Stop recording after 30 seconds. Click the the thumbnail in the bottom left.

Does anyone have a solution to allow these videos to play?

Comment: Latest [watchOS doesn’t run on series 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WatchOS) so I removed that part. If you can report the version you have installed, that might help refine the options.

Comment: It’s WatchOs8.7 but i would really like to use the Camera App offered by apple, if possible, because i dont like giving random companies access to the camera. Do later apple watches allow for this?

Comment: Great update. Hopefully as devices ship, you’ll get a no or yes or offers. Even third party option can help others and you get to select whichever answer works best  for you.